# Set property of ES6/ES2015 imported package

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-class, es6-modules

I am new in ES6 in ES5 I was able to set property of any require(imported) package something like this

```
var client = require('./client');
var conn = require('./conn/conn1.js');
client.conn = conn;
module.exports = client;
```

and in `client` package we were able to access client.conn. LIke this

```
function client(opts){
    // client.conn is accesable here
}
```

Now in ES6 I am trying to do like this

```
import client from './client'
import conn from './conn/conn1.js'
client.conn = conn;
export {client as default}
```

But I am not able to access `conn` variable. How can I do it in the right way.

Comment: I tried `extend` for client class like this `class extClient extends client`. Its working fine. Is there any better option then this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the function direclty as `import {client} from './client'` this way the only thing that you will be importing of the client.js will be the client fucntion.

see: [import statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: Yes you can import client, but what about setting new property of imported client ?\

Comment: The way you have it in your code, you will only be able to use client.conn if  in the client module you are also exporting conn